# For loop to find rows in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, performance, for-loop

I have two dataframes: one with daily stock prices (e.g. all U.S. stocks) and another one with historical constituents of an index (e.g. S&P 500).

I managed to create a for loop that checks if each stock, each day was part of the index. However, the loop might take ages to complete because the daily prices DF has 65.000.000 rows and the historical constituents DF has 15.000 rows. I tried with just some subsets of the DF and the code does what I need, but it would take days to complete. The speed of the loops gradually decreases the higher the iteration, so I think I might be doing something very inefficiently.

DF1: closing prices

```
  ticker date  price
1 AAPL   2018  150.10
2 AAPL   2019  220.50
3 MSFT   2018  50.60
4 MSFT   2019  70.90
```

DF2: constituents

```
  ticker date
1 AMZN   2018
2 AAPL   2018
3 FB     2018
3 AMZN   2019
4 AAPL   2019
5 MSFT   2019
```

Desired result:

```
  ticker date  price   in_index
1 AAPL   2018  150.10  yes
2 AAPL   2019  220.50  yes
3 MSFT   2018  50.60   no
4 MSFT   2019  70.90   yes
```

So, in 2018 AAPL is part of the index, while MSFT is not. And 2019 both AAPL and MSFT are part of the index.

Here is my code:

```
DF1['in_index'] = "no"

for row in range(len(DF1)):

    ticker = DF1.loc[row].ticker
    year = DF1.loc[row].year

    aux = DF2[(DF2.tic==ticker) & (DF2.year==year)]


    if len(aux) > 0:
        DF1['in_index'].loc[row] = 1
```

Is there a way to make this loop more efficient?

Comment: Would it be a possibility to merge the data, using `pd.merge` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way using `pandas.DataFrame.merge`:

```
new_df = df.merge(df2.assign(in_index="yes"), 
                  on=['ticker','date'], how='left').fillna({'in_index':'no'})
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
  ticker  date  price in_index
0   AAPL  2018  150.1      yes
1   AAPL  2019  220.5      yes
2   MSFT  2018   50.6       no
3   MSFT  2019   70.9      yes
```

Comment: what is the assign function doing? if instead of ```df2.assign(in_index="yes")``` I use ```df2['in_index']="yes"```, would that give the same result?

Comment: `df2.assign` is a one-liner trick, as opposed to `df2['in_index']="yes"` requires a separate line :P. Slightly different result though, as `df2` will **not** have `in_index` columns after the `merge` is done, while `df2['in_index']` will. Use as per your preference ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with **`indicator = True`** and [`DataFrame.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) 
taking advantage of the `_merge` column.

```
new_df = (df1.merge(df2,on = ['ticker','date'],how = 'left',indicator = 'in_index')
             .replace({'in_index':{'both':'yes','left_only':'no'}})
             )
print(new_df)
  ticker  date  price in_index
0   AAPL  2018  150.1      yes
1   AAPL  2019  220.5      yes
2   MSFT  2018   50.6       no
3   MSFT  2019   70.9      yes
```

Comment: Nice way of using `indicator`!

Comment: I forgot we can set the name of `indicator` @Luciano Matoso updated